# API REST - POST method with JSON doesn't support media type (415)

Tags: java, json, rest, api, post

I'm trying to implement a POST method in JSON and I'm not able to do it.

This is my code:

```
@POST
@Path("/assign")
@Consumes("application/json")
public Response createProjectInJSON(Projecte product) {

String result = "Product created : " + product;
return Response.status(201).entity(result).build();

}
```

And this is the "Projecte" class:

```
public class Projecte {

private String titol;
private String estat;
private String professor;
private String data_def, data_crea, data_mod, qualificacio;
private String descripcio, recursos, estudiant, estudi;

public Projecte(String titol, String estat, String professor) {
    this.titol = titol;
    this.estat = estat;
    this.professor = professor;
}
//getters and setters...
```

I use Postman writing in Body with format JSON the following data:

```
{
"titol": "hola",
"estat": "proposat",
"professor": "jack"
}
```

What I'm doing bad? Postman tell me that there is a status of 415 Unsupported Media Type.

What can I do to solve it? Thanks for all!

Miquel

Comment: well, what media type are you specifying when sending the request via postman?

Comment: In headers I put Content-type application/json and in body the code of the question

Comment: are you sure you are hitting the correct endpoint then? everything seems to be correct. Do you show anything on the logs? can you show us the URL you are using in POSTMAN?

Comment: This is the URL http://localhost:8080/SOBASE/webresources/rest/api/v1/tfg/assign
@ochi

Comment: When I send the request, I receive in header Content-type-> text/html
I don't know why, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly likely happening because you didn't set the `Content-Type` HTTP header to `application/json`. Clicking on the **Headers** tab in Postman will allow you to edit the headers directly. More details about headers in Postman can be found [here](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/requests#headers)

Comment: please include the relevant part in your answer.  Linking to external resources is fine but if the link becomes unavailable for some reason the answer would be incomplete without the relevant bits

Comment: @matt-mccoy I have this in Postman Header [link](https://imgur.com/a/8bHym)